# Creating a Toolbox in ArcGIS Pro that can export results into an image format

Tags: arcgis-pro, python-toolbox, arctoolbox

How can I create a Toolbox in ArcGIS Pro that can export results from point and line feature classes and combine them into just one image format (e.g. .jpg, .png).

like so

Comment: Do you mean "a tool"?

Comment: Have you created a test Python Toolbox (*.pyt) yet?  Why are you creating a Python Toolbox rather than a Standard Toolbox [*.tbc)?  The latter are easier if you are new to ArcPy.

Comment: What do you mean by "... can export results from..."? Are you talking about the map or layout?

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Pro has a function called ***ModelBuilder*** that allows you to chain geoprocessing tools together and save them as a custom tool. Here is some documentation to get you started. If you can provide more details regarding your workflow, I can provide a better suggestion.

[What is ModelBuilder?](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder-.htm)

[Use ModelBuilder](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/modelbuilder-quick-tour.htm)

Comment: Thank you. I want to combine the two future classes into just one image format. I don't know how to write code to use in a modelbuilder, can you help me?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what your end goal is. You are talking about Point and Line (Vector) data with a resulting output of an image (raster) data. Are you just trying to export a single map with some points and lines on it? If you can clarify your question in detail I may be able to offer more assistance.

Comment: My goal is to implement a feature class that is a point and a line. Converted to just one image My end result is just one picture.